# Trigger jenkins from JIRA-workflow

Tags: jenkins, jira-rest-api

we have jenkins CICD automated pipelines working great. we also trigger it via REST API with build Parameters.

Now, we have JIRA dashboard having custom workflow created where developers moves or changes queue of issues/stories to "ReadyForDeployment" once development is completed.

Now here, once developer moves queue to "ReadyForDeployment" :-

1. JIRA should prompt for 3 fields (ENV, PACKAGE_NAME_APP and
   PACKAGE_NAME_DB) those will be placed in jenkins URL like
   blahblahblah/buildWithParameters?ENV=${ENV}&  PACKAGE_NAME_APP=${PACKAGE_NAME_APP}&PACKAGE_NAME_DB=${PACKAGE_NAME_DB}
2. Basically upon queue change,webhook should be triggered whcih
   will take input/parameters from JIRA itself.

Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: Do you want to know whether its possible to do? or You want to know whether its good idea or not?

Comment: Triggering webhooks is possible. But triggering webhook through JIRA custom workflow and accepting input from users is what I want to do!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement whether its correct or not. But it can be possible to trigger jenkins from Jira useing Jira-weebhook and passing the parameters.

https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/webhooks